# Using CMYK/Transparent images in a PDF file

Tags: graphics, pdf, transparency, pdfx, cmyk

I am using PDFX / Lualatex to create a PDF/X-4 file. My problem is that the publisher is wanting the images in the file to be CMYK. Some of my images are transparent.

**The problem:**

- Latex only supports a limited number of image formats and does not allow for TIFF
- PNG images can have transparency, but do not support CMYK colour profiles
- JPG images do support CMYK, but cannot have transparency

So, what is my solution for including a transparent and CMYK image in a PDF file that the publisher will be able to use?

Comment: You can convert the image to a CMYK PDF. There are a limited number of open source tools that can do this. At least try ImageMagick. Scribus might also suit you.

Comment: You should seek another publisher. Every print shop must be able to correctly produce a valid PDF/X document. Since you are obviously not a color expert the conversion/separation should be done by the print shop. PDF/X-4 allows RGB content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only option is to convert the images to PDF which support CMYK and transparency and can by included by LaTeX.

You can do this using ImageMagick:

1. Create a simple transparent PNG (for example only):

   ```
   convert magick:logo -transparent white logo.png
   ```
2. Convert the PNG to a CMYK PDF (choose appropriate profiles for your printing environment):

   ```
   convert logo.png \
   -profile /usr/share/color/icc/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference_displayclass.icc \
   -profile /usr/share/color/icc/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc logo.pdf
   ```
3. Test with the following TeX file (`tex_logo.tex`):

   ```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{tikz}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
     % put a small grey square behind image to show the transparency
     \fill [black!20] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
     \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=54.19mm]{logo.pdf}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Use the GhostScript `tiffsep` device to produce separations and check that everything looks like it should:

   ```
   gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=tex_logo.tiff -sDEVICE=tiffsep \
   -sCompression=lzw -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
   -sDefaultRGBProfile=/usr/share/color/icc/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference_displayclass.icc \
   -sDefaultCMYKProfile=/usr/share/color/icc/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc \
   -sOutputICCProfile=/usr/share/color/icc/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc tex_logo.pdf
   ```

Here's the resulting composite output and separations:

**Composite**

[image: Composite output]

**Cyan separation**

[image: Cyan separation]

**Magenta separation**

[image: Magenta separation]

**Yellow separation**

[image: Yellow separation]

**Black separation**

[image: Black separation]

Comment: Such a nice suggestion...